# Update Webpage from server event

Tags: web-server

I have a project in mind, to create a webpage interfate to control an Arduino.

The communication between Arduino And RPI is achived via Serial, and bidirectional.

I made a little script that waits for a serial message, then sends that message to a php file.

My question is if that php file can update the page in any way when a message is recived.

Ex: if a button is pushed on the arduino, it will send a message to RPI that will be sent to a php file and .... somehow that php file will call a javascript function to do the page updating with the new button state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up using a service named [pusher](http://pusher.com/) for sending messages from Arduino (via Raspberry Pi) to the webpage. All in real time (a small delay but it's not a problem for me).

And It can b used in php, so it's all I ever wanted.

Now I can send messages to Arduino from the webpage, and arduino can update the page via pusher, so the page is a live representation of the Arduino's status, using Raspberry to do the "heavy lifting".

Answer (score 0):

First: this is *not* a good place to explore this question as it really has nothing to do with the raspberry pi.  It's a web programming question, so if you have any further questions about this, take them to somewhere more appropriate (e.g. Stack Overflow).

Servers can't call clients, that's the difference between servers and clients -- a client calls a server and the server answers.  The main reason is that clients can't answer a request for a connection from elsewhere -- otherwise they'd be servers.

Servers can connect to other servers (in which case they are taking the role of a client), but web browsers are not servers in any sense.  They're just clients, and you can't call them.  They call you.

However, in the context of HTTP (web) servers, you can get around this in limited ways.  There are two popular strategies here:

**Long Polling**: The client makes an ajax request which the server does not answer.  This keeps a connection to the client open.  When the server wants to contact the client arbitrarily, it answers the ajax request.  Since servers generally time connections out at a level lower than your application code, you need to repeat the request over and over when the connection is closed.

**Web sockets**: This is a newer technology that has largely superseded long-polling and is supported by (nearly) all contemporary browsers and http servers.  On the browser side, there is a (built-in)javascript API which is used to establish a "web socket" connection to the server.  This is a full duplex connection, so either party can arbitrarily send data to the other at any time.  I don't use php, but I am sure it has support for web sockets.

A simple variation on the long poll would be to just check in with the server at short intervals via ajax.  That's fine if you don't mind the latency and the server isn't that busy anyway, but if it is busy, that's a lot of added (pointless) traffic.